# Concatenate n number of numpy arrays columnwise in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arraylist

I know that we concatenate two 2-D numpy
arrays named `arr1` and `arr2` with same number of rows with the help of following command:

```
np.concatenate((arr1,arr2),axis=1)
```

But I have n number of numpy arrays (I haven't done global variable name  assignment to these arrays) in a **list** ,say, `list_array` which is a list containing n elements where each element is a 2-D array. We need looping or any efficient program would be okay.

**Question**

How can I concatenate these elements of the list which are 2-D arrays column wise?

Thank you

*I am not from CS background*. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: What's wrong with `np.concatenate(list_array, axis=1)`?

Comment: So this np.concatenate takes list as an argument?

Comment: It takes _sequence of array like_, just like your own example does: `(arr1, arr2)` ;)

Comment: Thank you so much..I didn't realise..you are Chris again..thanks Mr. Chris. You may write this as an answer. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a side note,

Concatenating with [`np.concatenate`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) on `axis=1` is equivalent to a horizontal stack: [`np.hstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html):

```
>>> np.hstack(list_array)
```

vs

```
>>> np.concatenate(list_array, axis=1)
```

Comment: look at the code for `hstack`.  Its use here doesn't improve anything.